# Recursively get all possible paths between 2 nodes

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I have a path which is a list of nodes. This path is already a shortest path return by basic Dijkstra. The nodes are the bus stops of various routes.

Each node can be serviced by a number of agencies. The list of agencies is stored in the node itself.

```
public class Path() {
    public List<Node> Node {get; set;}
}

public class Node() {
    public int Number {get; set;}
    public List<Agency> Agencies {get; set;}
}

public class Agency() {
    public int Number {get; set;}
}
```

Given the above data structure and a known path P, is it possible to recursively return all possible route combinations, sorted by minimum number of agency changes?

Or would a Ford-Fulkerson algorithm fit better in this case?

Comment: Did you try anything to get the paths ?

Comment: @deathismyfriend Trying to implement recursion, but I thought maybe there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant of [k shortest paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing), where k is unbounded (remove the check `count < k`).

Comment: I think in this case, k > n because a node can have multiple agencies.

Comment: Yep, my mistake.  You can just remove the stop condition for k paths, and keep going until there are no more possible paths.